# How to find where I have declared an "@+id/widget" in XML, starting from R.java?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-xml, r.java-file

It happens to me to declare widgets by **id** in XML files (`@+id/widget`) and to forget in which XML file I have declared, especially when I have a lots of **ids** and XML files.

Usually I look for them in `R.java` where they are nice sorted. But I see nowhere the XML file where they are declared. And I have to browse through all XML files which is annoying.

On **right_click-> Open Declaration**, `R.java` is opened, at line:

`public static final int widget=0x7f090012;` maybe this is the normal behaviour but

I wander if is there a way to get from `R.java` in the XML file where I have declared the widget, like `@+id/widget`. Or any other quick access method.

I'm using [Eclipse, downloaded with "ADT Bundle"](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Eclipse IDE, Hold `CTRL key` and point the mouse the `id` in your java code, then a list shown, `-Open Deceleration in *`, example:

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

hold `ctrl` and point the mouse on `textView1`.

*if you are using MAC then use `Command` instead `Ctrl`*

Comment: Thanks to all for your good answers but I found this the easiest way.

Answer (score 4):

while pressing window/command key if you in macos or ctrl if you in windows move your mouse pointer to `@+id/widget` and you will see different declaration places like : 
/[image]

you will see then different xml file where you declare that id. just click any of .xml file then

Comment: Wow! I didn't know that one.

Comment: its very useful @StephanBranczyk . what you say :)

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, press Ctrl+H and type "@+id/widget".
The search result will tell you all the files that contains "@+id/widget"....

Answer (score 1):

in Eclipse environment

- click your android project then Ctrl+H
- click File Search tab
- type-->widget
- choose file name patter in the next text field---> *.xml
- in Scope section, select Workspace, hit Search button.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get it from the root directory of all the xml files.

**STEP 1:** Select your layout folder,

[image]

**STEP 2:** Press `Control+H`,
[image]

->enter your search keyword i.e. `widget` // I have used `btnDone`

->select the scope

->Click on Search button

**STEP 3:** Look at the accurate results provided in `Search` tab,
[image]

I hope it will be helpful !

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this kind of problem it's better to name your ids in correlation with the xml file name. For example if you have home.xml start your ids with "home_".
You shouldn't need to go through R.java.
You can do a file search with eclipse to find "@+id/widget".

Answer (score 0):

If you press the ctrl button while placing your cursor on the variable names in the R.java, the link to its corresponding xml file will pop up.